# Listview onItemSelected doesn't fire off when navigating back to the previous selected item

Tags: android, android-listview, google-tv, android-event

My activity includes 2 fragments. Fragment 1 in the left contains a ListView, let's call listView1, and fragment 2 in the right contains a GridView. I implemented a onItemSelectedListener to send data to a remote server each time an item in listView1 is selected (users use D-pad to navigate). The listener is as below:

```
listView1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                                          int position, long id){
        //send data to sever here
        sendData();
    }
});
```

It's ok when I navigate around in the ListView. The sendData() method insides onItemSelected() was called as normal. But the problem is each time I navigate to my GridView and then navigate back to the previous selected item in listView1, the onItemSelected and sendData() method haven't fired off any more. I did a  search and found in [android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) that the onItemSelected method is invoked only when the newly selected position is different from the previously selected position.

So how can i make onItemSelected fire off even when I navigate back to previous selected item?

Thanks in advances!

Answer (score 0):

Use onListItemClick instead:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    sendData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin S. But it requires users to perform "press enter" action which may reduces their experience since they use D-Pad to navigate.